# what happen if using wait and notify methods not in a synchronized blocks ? is it useful?

Tags: java, synchronization

Two questions regarding synchronization

1. What happen if using wait and notify methods in non synchronized blocks ? Is it useful ?
2. Should synchronized object be the same as the object of the wait method ? Can I do like this :

   ```
   synchronized (o) {
       try {
           this.wait();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You got your test program. Test it yourself. You will get the answer pretty quickly.

Comment: Did you try running the code or reading the javadoc?  What don't you understand from these obvious ways to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An `IllegalThreadStateException` is thrown if the current thread fails to `synchronize` on an object before calling its `wait()` or `notify()` methods. So, no, it isn't useful.
2. Yes, to reiterate the above, the thread must `synchronize` on the same instance upon which it invokes `wait()` or `notify()`. So the example will only work if `o == this`.

I don't find good reasons to use `wait()` and `notify()` since `java.util.concurrent` was introduced, and `synchronized` is less useful now too. I recommend the higher-level tools in that package to both beginners (as easier to use) and advanced (more powerful and correct) programmers.

Comment: rgarding point 1 : who own the monitor of an object that is not on synchronize ? nobody ?

Comment: @yryrp Right, no thread owns the monitor until one enters the critical section.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
You can't call `wait()` or `notify()/notifyAll()` outside of `synchronized` blocks that synchronize on the the object the method calls belong to. If you try, you'll get an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

**2.**
You are *required* to synchronize on the same object that your `wait()/notify()/notifyAll()` calls belong to. For instance, your code will throw an IMSE as written. You'll want to call `synchronized(this){ ...` instead.